# Finding an expression for the rate of change of a spherical container

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume, related-rates

Hi all I was wondering how I would find an expression for the rate of change of a spherical container which is being filled up with a liquid.

I am aware that I must use Derivatives as the liquid is being filled at a $\frac{dV_1}{dt}$.

$$ 
V_1 = \pi y^2 \left(\frac{r-y}{3}\right) 
$$
is the equation which defines the volume of the liquid in the container.

What I am told is to differentiate the equation with respect to $y$ and then rearrange for $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rate of change of depth of a liquid in a spherical container](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670234/rate-of-change-of-depth-of-a-liquid-in-a-spherical-container)

Comment: Have you differentiated the equation with respect to $y$ and then rearranged for $\frac{dy}{dt}$? What did you get?

Answer (score 1):

$$V_1 = \pi y^2 \left(\frac{r-y}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi ry^2}{3}-\frac{\pi y^3}{3}$$
$$\frac{dV_1}{dt}=\frac{\pi r}{3}(2y)\frac{dy}{dt}-\frac{\pi}{3}(3y^2)\frac{dy}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dV_1}{dt}=\left(\frac{2\pi ry}{3}-\pi y^2\right)\frac{dy}{dt}$$
Now you can rearrange to get $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ in terms of $\dfrac{dV_1}{dt}$.